# Create html table using php using group by

Tags: php, html, mysql

My mysql database has the following:

```
productid | productname | category
    1            XYZ         News
    2            ZYX         News 
    3            vcb         Info
```

I want to display them in a table group by category like this

```
Category : News
xyz 
zyx

Category : Info
vcb

Etc....
```

currently i am using

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM database Group By category";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {


echo "<table cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'>
<thead>
<tr>
<th>id</th>
<th>name</th>
<th>catergory</th>

</tr>
</thead>";

$i = 0;

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
    if($i%2 == 0)
   {
      $class = 'even';
   }
   else
   {
      $class = 'odd';
   }

  {
  echo "<tbody>";
  echo "<tr class='$class'>";
   echo "<td>" . $row['productid'] . "</td>";
echo "<td style='font-weight: bold; text-align: center;'>" . $row['productname '] . "</td>"; 
echo "<td style='font-weight: bold; text-align: center;'>" . $row['category '] . "</td>";     
  echo "</tr>";
 }
       $i++;
    }

echo "</tbody>";
echo "</table>";
} else {
    echo "";
}
```

Comment: Can you show us some code that you've tried?

Comment: ok so you have data base queries to get the data, and a table to display it. is there an error, issue, something not working?

Answer (score 0):

You can use MySQL's [`GROUP_CONCAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat), which returns a comma concatenated string -

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(productname) as productname FROM database Group By category
```

Then your `$row['productname']` will look like `XYZ,ZYX`.

You can then use php to format the data - ie.

```
echo str_replace(',','<br />',$row['productname']);
```